# SDCard permission issue

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, sd-card, 4.3-jelly-bean, android-sdk

I have a Samsung S3 which I have installed Cyanogenmod on with a view to carry out some procedures with root permissions.

At the minute I am trying to create a .img file of the userdata memory block using the DD command in the adb shell. I have a 32GB SD card which initially was formatted as FAT32 and therefore failed once the .img file reached 4GB. I expected as much but I wanted to check things were going ok before I reformatted the card.

I then formatted the SDCard as ext4 using gparted. I noticed on my ubuntu machine that the card had root ownership so I changed that to user and I can read and write files in nautilus fine.

Switching back to the adb shell, I carried out the same command as below (which is what I previously used when it was formatted as FAT32) and I get a permission error. Its driving me insane, I've tried chown'ing and chmod'ing till the cows come home and still nothing working.

Commands I'm using

```
$ ./adb shell
shell@mo:/ $ cd dev/block/platform/dw_mmc/by-name
shell@mo:/ $ su
root@m0:/ # dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 of=/storage/sdcard1/userdata.img

#error message is
/storage/sdcard1/userdata.img: cannot open for write: Permission denied
```

I've tried

```
chmod 777 /storage/sdcard1
```

and various other chowning, but still get the same issue. Am I doing something stupid (probably!) but any tips appreciated.

**Edit**

Relevant output of mount:

```
/dev/block/vold/179:17 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 ext4 rw,dirsync,context=u:object_r:sdcard_external:s0,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_xattr,barrier=1 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
```

Output of ls -l in storage/

```
dr-xr-xr-x root     root              2014-10-01 08:15 emulated
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2014-10-01 08:15 sdcard0 -> /storage/emulated/legacy
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-10-01 08:13 sdcard1
drwxrwxr-x system   system            2014-10-01 08:15 usbdisk0
```

**Edit**

Output of echo'ing foo to a text file

```
root@m0:/ # echo foo > /storage/sdcard1/foobar.txt
sh: can't create /storage/sdcard1/foobar.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you checked the SD card's mount options? Could be flagged as read-only, but you may be able to remount it to fix it. I think external cards get mounted read-only by default on newer versions of Android (not sure about that, though, my device has no SD card slot).

Comment: i thought that to be honest, i tried mount -o rw,remount /storage/sdcard1 but again no difference

Comment: @eldarerathis I would wonder if they get mounted r/o even with that stupid KK change, as that would render even the systems camera app void – plus the ability of apps to write to their own directories there, which still exists with KK. // m0atz: please check the output of `mount`, and do a `ls -l` on the directory where the card is mounted to, plus on the card's root directory. Any notable things that "jump into your face" there?

Comment: @Izzy: It must have just been specific to certain devices, then. It was a problem with the Motorola Xoom, and I feel like there were at least a couple other devices that behaved similarly, but I switched to Nexus devices (lacking SD card slots) quite some time ago.

Comment: @eldarerathis thanks for the comments, updated question with outputs of mount and ls -l. There's nothing on the sdcard so ls -l in the root directory of the /storage/sdcard1 is empty. Nothing stands out at me to be honest.

Comment: @m0atz I've truncated that a little to leave only the relevant stuff in (easier to read/follow). But that looks fine: card is mounted r/w, and the `sdcard_rw` group (plus root) are granted full access to it. Btw: Your original post doesn't indicate whether your `su` succeeded (what prompt belongs before the `dd` call: is it a `$` or a `#`?) – could you please fill that gap? Also: Does a simple `echo foo > /storage/sdcard1/foobar.txt`, run as root, succeed? Is your system's camera app able to store pictures on the SDCard?

Comment: Thanks Izzy - much easier to read as you've suggested. I get a "#" at the prompt following the su but get permission denied when echo'ing foo (question updated). cheers

Comment: Also Izzy, tried to set the storage of the camera to default to the SD card and now the camera app crashes. crazy.

Comment: @m0atz can you try to echo foo /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1/foobar.txt as root? I think sdcard is mounted two times, second time with fuse that makes permissions harder to understand.

Comment: hey Crayon - that worked! I've used that path on my dd command and its running also. Many thanks for the input!

Comment: Glad that worked, coming from linux sometimes I find android a bit confusing about permissions.